# Access sitemap from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

**Background**

I'm currently working on a monolithic asp.net web application which uses sitemaps to render menu. The access to each sitemap node is determined by permissions defined in web.config file(s) for each roles.

Roles defined in the web.config files are not actual user roles, but they are virtual roles, and calculated based on the application license and the actual user role.

Now, new feature of the application is built using Web API and AnguarJS, and Asp .Net pages are not used. But menu still need to display in new pages, in order to access other parts of the system.

So plan is to somehow access the sitemap via API Controller to populate menu using AnngularJS.

**Question**

One possibility is to read the sitemap directly as XML file, but that will not hide menu items user does not have access.

The SiteMapProvider need to be in a asp.net page / control to use. Do anyone know a way to use it within an API?

Answer (score 0):

Should still be able to access it via `System.Web.SiteMap`